# Populate table ADF Oracle Dynamically

Tags: java, oracle-adf

Is there a way populate a RichTable in an ADF Form dynamically with data extracted from a Web Service using a java class?

First, the user will click on the "get Invoices" button which will extract data from a external web service. Then the extracted data should be iterated and shown in a RichTable on the form.

I created a DataControl associated to a bean (which have a class inside with all the attributes shown on the table) and put it as an iterator table on the form.

Each time the user clicks on the button the created object should be cleaned, filled again with the new data and then shown on the Rich Table.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Java Class with a method that fetches the values from the Web Service into a collection.
Then expose that java class as a data control.
Then base a page on that data control, with a button that executes the method and a table that shows the results.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_bean_dc/tut_bean_dc.html
and
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_web_services/tut_web_services_6.html